# Problem when using if __name__ == "__main__": in Python

Tags: python

I have a file called `game.py` that contains the following code:

```
import other
items = []

for _ in range(1, 15):
    a = other.myfunction()
    items.append(a)
min = min(items)
max = max(items)
print(min)
print(max)
```

When I run this function from the terminal using `python game.py`, it works perfectly fine and I get the two values printed.

However, when I modify the script by adding `def main():` at the beginning and `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` at the end of the script and run it from the terminal using `./game.py`, I get the following error:

```
File "./game.py", line 8, in <module>
min = min(items)
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Why wouldn't the SAME code run if I just added a function definition? I've never had this problem before...

I'm pasting here my code using `def main():` at the beginning and `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` at the end of the script:

```
import other
items = []

def main():
   for _ in range(1, 15):
       a = other.myfunction()
       items.append(a)
   min = min(items)
   max = max(items)
   print(min)
   print(max)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: This code can't work. `append ` works in place. Get rid of the assignment in `items = items.append(a)`. After the first iteration, `items` is `None`

Comment: What if you define 'items =[]' inside main()?

Comment: No repro. Both snippets throw a different exception than you claimed. Please post an actual [mcve].

Comment: Use `main(items)` instead, as your function expects its value. And add `import other` inside the main() function definition.

Comment: What does `other.myfunction()` return?

Comment: @Arihant no it doesn't. And your edit has made your advice worse.

Comment: I'm sorry I made that mistake with append, but I'm still having the problem... I edited my question

Comment: @jhomr a  number, though it's a different number each time (pseudorandom)

Comment: It's clearly visible in the traceback you posted that the exception happens at module-level, and not in a `main` function. The code in your question is different from the code that produces that error, so I repeat my request for a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your problem is next:
you should use different names for your variables instead of using function names (`min_` and `max_` instead of `min` and `max` which are functions names).
Also it is a good practise to return a value by your script if it is successful (or failure) run.

```
import other
import sys

items = []

def main():
    for _ in range(1, 15):
       a = other.myfunction()
       items.append(a)
    min_ = min(items)
    max_ = max(items)
    print(min_)
    print(max_)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
   sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped

Answer (score 0):

`items = items.append(a)` results in the return value of `items.append(a)` which is `None`.

You should modify that line to simply be `items.append(a)`

Also, which having the declaration of `items` outside of the function, you should have it inside, unless there's a specific reason for it.